# Deformation of the nematic phase of liquid crystals surviving in the solid state

Tags: crystal-structure, phase, liquid-crystals

Does anyone know if I were to cool a liquid crystal with a deformed nematic phase quickly, if it will preserve the deformation in the crystal lattice?

I didn't find any information in classical books on liquid crystals.